# Is there anything like a timelapse showing the Alpha Centauri stars orbiting around each other?

Tags: observational-astronomy, orbit, photography, angular-diameter

It is my understanding that the angular separation between Alpha Centauri A & B is more than enough for even amateur telescopes to resolve as 2 separate stars. Going by the plot below, over the past 20 years there should be noticeable movement showing them orbiting. Do we have any images/videos that capture this movement?

[image: Orbit_Alpha_Centauri_AB_arcsec.png)]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit_Alpha_Centauri_AB_arcsec.png) click for full size

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any infos on this specific case.

But as I remember, there was a similar study from NASA a while ago, observed with the Hubble telescope:

https://hubblesite.org/contents/news-releases/2013/news-2013-22.html#section-id-2

There is a nice animation that show the proper motion of Proxima Centauri relative to background stars (not specified) between 2000 and 2010. The attempt was to detect the presence of planets around Proxima Centauri.